# matlab - variable in plot title

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to do

```
for i = 1 : size(N, 2)
    figure(i);
    title('N = %d', i);
%other stuff
```

but setting the title doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 10):

Because you forgot to add `sprintf`

```
for i = 1 : size(N, 2) 
figure(i); 
title(sprintf('N = %i', i)); %# %i for integer
%other stuff
end
```

Answer (score 8):

num2str should also works.

```
title(['N = ',num2str(i)]);
```