# MATLAB question: quote value of variables in the tile of a plot

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [matlab - variable in plot title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629458/matlab-variable-in-plot-title)

I would like to quote the value of variables defined in the m-file in the plot such as

let us say I define

```
d = 1;
```

in the MATLAB code. I want to plot with the title such as

```
title('The Distribution of Some Variable when the Parameter is %d')
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
title(['The Distribution of Some Variable when the Parameter is ' num2str(d)])
```

Brackets `['concatenate ' 'strings']` and `num2str()` converts a number (integer or decimal) to a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
title(sprintf('The Distribution of Some Variable when the Parameter is %d', d));
```